# DocuSign and Office 365 SharePoint Online via REST API

Tags: docusignapi

I will have the documents uploaded to our SharePoint Online library and from there I want to send document for signature of the customer and track the status. I don't want to get into DocuSign templates or any other thing as we will have multiple documents for multiple customers and using SharePoint Online as repository and DocuSign as just for signing tool.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the specifics of your use case, it's possible that the "DocuSign for SharePoint" connector might give you the functionality you require (without any need for development work on your part).  See https://www.docusign.com/partner/docusign-for-sharepoint-online for information about the (free) connector.

If the connector doesn't meet your needs, then you should be able to develop a custom integration between your SharePoint Online library and DocuSign -- provided that SharePoint Online has an API by which you can access the documents, create/update objects (to track DocuSign status), etc.  The DocuSign API can be used to integrate DocuSign with any other system, as long as that system provides a way for you to programmatically access its contents (i.e., an API).

From the DocuSign side of things, the DocuSign Developer Center (https://www.docusign.com/developer-center) is a good starting point for understanding the API.  Additionally, you'll want to become very familiar with the REST API Guide (https://08d1d92f490618f41c65-8fb00e97ac499a7066a18ce9c66b019b.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf).  I'd suggest that you review these resources as starting point, and post more specific API questions here on SO if/when they arise.

Comment: I have the DocuSign app installed on my SharePoint Online. However, rather going in SharePoint Online manually and performing Signing, Sending etc operations I need to automate those steps.

Comment: Got it.  In that case, you'll need to develop the integration by using both the SharePoint API and the DocuSign API.  The DocuSign Dev Center contains a wealth of info about getting started with the DocuSign API, so I'd start there, if I were you.